# Remix error - Uncaught Error: Expected fetch controller: :R69l:

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I cannot figure out whats going wrong here. The error occurs intermittently on either page load or route change and I haven't been able to determine what causes it. Note that route changes and page loads to the same destination doesn't always throw this error, most of the time its fine then sometimes this error occurs:

```
Uncaught Error: Expected fetch controller: :rb:
    at invariant3 (history.ts:494:11)
    at abortFetcher (router.ts:2599:5)
    at router.ts:2122:44
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AbortSignal.abortPendingFetchRevalidations (router.ts:2122:28)
    at abortFetcher (router.ts:2600:16)
    at abortStaleFetchLoads (router.ts:2635:11)
    at handleFetcherAction (router.ts:2183:5)
  invariant3                       @ history.ts:494
  abortFetcher                     @ router.ts:2599
  (anonymous)                      @ router.ts:2122
  abortPendingFetchRevalidations   @ router.ts:2122
  abortFetcher                     @ router.ts:2600
  abortStaleFetchLoads             @ router.ts:2635
  handleFetcherAction              @ router.ts:2183
  await in handleFetcherAction (async)
  fetch2                           @ router.ts:1931
  (anonymous)                      @ index.tsx:1551
  (anonymous)                      @ index.tsx:1695
  (anonymous)                      @ MyComponent.tsx:51
  commitHookEffectListMount        @ react-dom.development.js:23150
  commitPassiveMountOnFiber        @ react-dom.development.js:24926
  commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
  commitPassiveMountEffects_begin  @ react-dom.development.js:24878
  commitPassiveMountEffects        @ react-dom.development.js:24866
  flushPassiveEffectsImpl          @ react-dom.development.js:27039
  flushPassiveEffects              @ react-dom.development.js:26984
  (anonymous)                      @ react-dom.development.js:26769
  workLoop                         @ scheduler.development.js:266
  flushWork                        @ scheduler.development.js:239
  performWorkUntilDeadline         @ scheduler.development.js:533
```

The only common factor is that the error seems to happen when using a useFetcher in a useEffect to make a .submit() call to a resource route:

```
const fetcher = useFetcher();

useEffect(() => {
    fetcher.submit(
        null,
        {
            method: "post",
            action: "/some/route/"
        }
    );
}, [])
```

But, the data always gets fetched and the component renders as expected. Also note that this error occurs whether body is submitted or not as in the above example.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you navigating around your app "quickly"? This just looks like the framework canceling in-flight requests when you navigate away from a page that no longer needs the results because it's no longer mounted. Can you [edit] to provide any further context on the issue? Do you have any debugging details? What are your reproduction steps?

Comment: I could be, i'm refreshing pages and navigating to test things. Does that mean this isn't something to worry about in production?

Comment: Dunno, the "uncaught error" seems problematic though. I don't see where fetch requests are cancelled in either the `useFetcher` and `useSubmit` hooks, and based on that stacktrace it seems to originate in the router instance. A quick Google search also turned up minimal results. Maybe wrap your submit in a `try/catch`?

Comment: Ive tried that, just tested it again to be certain. but the error doesn't get caught, and the fetcher returns data as if it were a successful call. Im going to update my question with the full stack trace